# hide /var/ /lib/ proftpd

Tags: ftp

i would like to hide ONLY the dirs in users root dir.
and i want it to be genereic (i have mysql users)

i have :

```
<Directory />
   HideFiles ((lib|var|etc|tmp).*)$
   <Limit ALL DIRS WRITE>
     IgnoreHidden on
   </Limit>
</Directory>
```

how to make it work only for the users root(home) dir ??

so for example it will work for

```
~/lib/*
```

but not for

```
~/example.com/lib/*
```

Comment: i think it might be possible using DenyFilter but i have no idea how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i think it is impossible using that command so i just created a group `www-hidden` and

```
HideGroup www-hidden
```

...

but if someone knows a way to do it without this workaround please post

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not yet supported; there's a long standing [feature request](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2260) for support for this sort of thing.  The fact that you've asked about this feature here on ServerFault means I should see how hard it would be to implement this feature.

Comment: Hi, did you forget a link? Your text references a post on [so], but there doesn't seem to be a link to one.